# Level creation save points

Tags: portal-2

I'm a big fan of the larger, multi-part puzzles. Now that I can marvel in my own mind-bending magnificence with the Perpetual Testing Initiative, is it possible to install autosave points into a level I have created?

Comment: Just a note, [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://www.gamedev.stackexchange.com) allows questions about game mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not. You have to use the Portal 2 SDK, as the Auto Save is an object.

The Perpetual Testing Initiative is for maps you release for the community, and are meant to be small enough that you dont need auto-saves (As auto saves are mainly used with big maps that have 5 or 6 rooms / chambers)

EDIT:

You can however upload maps made / edited in the Source SDK's Hammer Map Editor to the work, as part of the PTI

(Thanks to Richard Benson for informing me of that)

Comment: It's worth adding to this that even maps made in Hammer & the SDK can be uploaded to the workshop to be part of the PTI.

Comment: @RichardBenson oh ok, i didnt know that you could, as i would think it could lead to people being unfairly rated, but now i know, ill add it in.... thanks

Comment: Gareth Jones is correct in saying that you cannot add save points into a level that you create, but you can still use the quick save feature which will then create a save point for any user that remembers to do so.